# Newlines not displaying in CodeIgniter Email Class

Tags: codeigniter

I seem to be doing something wrong when it comes to prepping a message for the CodeIgniter Email Class.  I've got the following code:

```
$message =  "Registration Confirmation and Receipt";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "Thank you for registering for MAGIC Live. Your credit card receipt and a complete confirmation of your registration is below. Please keep it for your records.\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "Credit card: XXXX XXXX XXXX ".$group['last4'];
$message .= " Exp: ".$group['exp_month']."/".$group['exp_year']."\r\n";
$message .= "data";
$this->email->message($message);
```

Only two sets of newline characters next to each other seem to take effect.  The outputted email looks like this:

```
Registration Confirmation and Receipt Thank you for registering for MAGIC Live. Your credit card receipt and a complete confirmation of your registration is below. Please keep it for your records.

Credit card: XXXX XXXX XXXX 4242 Exp: 3/2015 data
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: probably using HTML for mail. try replacing "\r\n"'s with "<br>".

Comment: or use `$this->email->message(nl2br($message));`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. CI defaults to text for email. Just for kicks I forced it by setting the config 'mailtype' value to text and it didn't have any impact. I think I'm going to switch to HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the email configuration. You can set the newline character. Default is \n.

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"
```